# R/Dplyr create a larger dataframe from dataframe with cells that have have comma separated cell values

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyr, unnest

I'm working off a dataframe like the below. I've done my best to format it in SO. The important thing is that there are the same number of comma separated entries in `person`, `personparty` and `sponsordate` (I've truncated the cells, so they may not be the same in this example but they are the same in the dataset).

```
bill                                               status       person                       personparty       sponsordate
A bill to amend chapter 44 of title 18, ....        2ND Sen.   David Vitter [R-LA]           Republican             12/05/2015
A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds....  RESTRICT    Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Barbara Boxer [D-CA]  Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat,     21/05/2014, 02/06/2015, 05/04/2017, 22/05/2014, 21/07/2014, 09/06/2014, 02/06/2014, 12/06/2014, 21/05/2014, 02/06/2014, 21/05/2014
```

I want to create a new dataframe of five columns. I essentially want to unlist these (non list) values into one larger dataframe.

The final dataframe should have a row for the ith comma separated entry in , keeping the same column values for `bill` and `status`.

So for example from the second row in my example dataset, there would be a row with the bill name (A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds....), status (RESTRICT), Ed Markey, Democrat, 21/05/2014. The next row would be the 2nd entry from the comma separated values (same bill name, same status, Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Democrat, 02/06/2015), etc.

For rows with just one value in the three last columns, they'd stay the same.

How do I essentially unnest these list-like values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `separate_rows`.

**Assumption:** Comma separated values in these three columns are of same numbers. It is based on the excerpt from your post - *"The important thing is that there are the same number of comma separated entries in person, personparty and sponsordate"*

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(person, personparty, sponsordate, sep=",")
```

Output is:

```
                                                bill   status                     person personparty
1       A bill to amend chapter 44 of title 18, .... 2ND Sen.        David Vitter [R-LA]  Republican
2 A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds.... RESTRICT      Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA]    Democrat
3 A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds.... RESTRICT      Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA]    Democrat
4 A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds.... RESTRICT      Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA]    Democrat
5 A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds.... RESTRICT  Sen. Barbara Boxer [D-CA]    Democrat
  sponsordate
1  12/05/2015
2  21/05/2014
3  02/06/2015
4  05/04/2017
5  22/05/2014
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(bill = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A bill to amend chapter 44 of title 18, ....", 
"A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds...."), class = "factor"), 
    status = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2ND Sen.", "RESTRICT"
    ), class = "factor"), person = structure(1:2, .Label = c("David Vitter [R-LA]", 
    "Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Barbara Boxer [D-CA]"
    ), class = "factor"), personparty = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat", 
    "Republican"), class = "factor"), sponsordate = structure(1:2, .Label = c("12/05/2015", 
    "21/05/2014, 02/06/2015, 05/04/2017, 22/05/2014"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("bill", 
"status", "person", "personparty", "sponsordate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I manually wrote out a loop to this that totaled about 75 lines. SO yeah, this is better.

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have understood what you want, so I begin with the data frame I assume you have:

```
df=structure(list(bill = c("A bill to amend chapter 44 of title 18, .<U+0085>", 
"A bill to authorize the appropriation of funds...."), status = c("2ND Sen.", 
"RESTRICT"), person = c("David Vitter [R-LA]", "Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Ed Markey [D-MA], Sen. Barbara Boxer [D-CA]"
), personparty = c("Republican", "Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat, Democrat,"
), sponsordate = c("12/05/15", "21/05/2014, 02/06/2015, 05/04/2017, 22/05/2014, 21/07/2014, 09/06/2014, 02/06/2014, 12/06/2014, 21/05/2014, 02/06/2014, 21/05/2014"
)), .Names = c("bill", "status", "person", "personparty", "sponsordate"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(bill = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), status = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), person = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), personparty = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), sponsordate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("bill", "status", "person", "personparty", 
"sponsordate")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Now I understand you want to expand the 2nd row to many rows. If 'many' means all combinations of vector elements of cols 3,4,5 of row 2 and append it to the data frame (overlapping row 2) you can do it as follows:

```
librart(stringr)
x01=str_split(df$person[2],",")[[1]]
x02=str_split(df$personparty[2],",")[[1]]
x03=str_split(df$sponsordate[2],",")[[1]]
x04=expand.grid(x01,x02,x03)
df0=do.call("rbind", replicate(nrow(x04), df[2,], simplify = FALSE))
df0[2:(nrow(x04)+1),3:5]=as.matrix(x04)
```

Hope this helps